# Seach a text or number from a list in another sheet and highlight each instance

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets with more than 50K data points (Sheet 1), and a list with numbers and Alpha-Numeric texts more than 30K(Sheet 2, Column A). I want a macro code to search each cell from sheet 2 in sheet 1 and change background color of each instance. 
Example:
**Searching: ABC123**, should find cell such as "Stack_Overflow**Abc123**"##@@".

I found some code, but so far they don't satisfy my requirement:

```
Sub HighlightListed() 
Dim strConcatList As String 
Dim cell As Range 
For Each cell In Sheets("List").Range("A1:A30") 
       strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|" 
Next cell 

For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Data").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Data").UsedRange) 'I assume my problem is here somewhere, its only highlights exact results. 
'If i am looking for "ABC123" it should also highlight cell like "PQRABC123" or ""XYZ_ABC123" 
    If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then 
          cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 
    End If 
Next cell 
End Sub
```

I am fairly new to VBA, so detailed explanation will be most helpful

Comment: hi, if include your code so far then we can correct it, then people are more inclined to help as it takes less of their time - so can help more people - they are rarely inclined to just give you the code, especially without evidence of effort.

Comment: Thanks for replying instantly, the problem is, i am really new to VBA coding, i didn't wrote any code but tried some of VBA codes from google, some of them are highlighting only Cell where there is exact match or some of them are highlighting all the instances but searching only one text string. though i will get you the code which i was trying to edit for my needs.

Comment: Below code is nearest match for my requirement, but it doesn't highlight, if the cells text is not exact match:

Comment: `Sub HighlightListed()

Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Sheets("List").Range("A1:A30")
strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|"
Next cell
For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Data").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Data").UsedRange)
'I assume my problem is here somewhere, its only highlights exact results.
'If i am looking for "ABC123" it should also highlight cell like "PQRABC123" or ""XYZ_ABC123"
If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next cell
End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub HighlightListed()
        Dim searches As New Collection
        Dim search As Variant
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Sheets("List").Range("A1:A30")
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                searches.Add cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell
        For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Data").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Data").UsedRange)
            For Each search In searches
                If InStr(0, cell.Value, Cstr(search), 1) > 0 Then
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next search
        Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Again Julian for speedy response. The above code is not just highlighting  the results but also highlighting all cells in UsedRange in A column.

Comment: Are all fields in the search range filled with values?
I edited the code, please try it again with this attempt.

Comment: Bingooo! This seems to be working. Thaaaaaaankuuuu Sooooo Mucchhhh, Awesome!... Great job Julian. Please explain me the logic too. where i was wrong? Now i will test this on my actual data.

Comment: No problem!
So, your code added up all search strings to one big string and tested for each cell in the data range, if its value is contained in the master string.
So now if the value of one of the cells in the data range had additional characters the result was false. My script adds all search terms to a collection (sort of an array). In a nested loop for each data value all search terms are tested if they are in the string.
Please never use such code as you provided :P

Comment: Oh, i forgot something, please use the now edited code, it should speed up the code a fair bit.

Comment: Sub HighlightPossible()
Dim seaRches As New Collection
Dim seARch As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
' Modified this considering unpredictable range limit.
Dim LstRw As Integer
LstRw = Worksheets(2).Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For Each Cell In Sheets("List").Range("A2:A" & LstRw)
If Cell.Value <> "" Then
seaRches.Add Cell.Value
End If
Next Cell
For Each Cell In Intersect(Sheets("Data").Range("B:B"), Sheets("Data").UsedRange)
For Each seARch In seaRches
If InStr(Cell.Value, seARch) > 0 Then
Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Exit For
End If
Next seARch
Next Cell
End Sub

Comment: Hi @Julian Kuchlbauer, i need some help, this code is good, was working fine too.. but i believe i messed up somewhere. Its not highlighting the data properly. I would like to highlight text whether its CAPs or LOWER case. whatever case it is it should highlight.

Comment: I also trying to work on that the code should ignore header's LIST and DATA sheet.

Comment: To achieve the case independent comparison, just add the third parameter to the instr with the value 1: Instr(Cell.Value, search, 1).
What do you mean with ignore headers?

Comment: You mean should i make it "If InStr(cell.Value, search, 1) > 0 Then". its giving error, i hope i did correctly. and We have given the range as Sheets("Data").Range("B:B") so its highlighting Header text if matches.

Comment: One more thing, how do i comment code, don't understand how to comment code in the format you posted above.

Comment: What error do you get?
Oh, i see what you mean now with the headers, i think about a solution.

Comment: For which line? What text does it say?

Comment: for this line :If InStr(cell.Value, search, 1) > 0 Then and it says 
 
I am getting run time error '13'

Comment: try enclosing search in Cstr(): Cstr(search)

Comment: I guess i am getting more messed up Julian could you please edit the code above, it would be great help.

Comment: Are you checking on this?

Comment: Yes, ill do it this afternoon

Comment: i got the instr fixed, take a look at the edited code

Comment: Its working "If InStr(0, cell.Value, Cstr(search), 1) > 0 Then" but when made it "If InStr(1, cell.Value, Cstr(search), 1) > 0 Then". Thanks Julian

Comment: It worked with the second solution? So, are all your questions cleared now?